# Retrieve all attributes of a subscriber using FUEL SDK PYTHON

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk, python

I am trying to get all the attributes of a subscriber including some custom attributes. I know I can retrieve the attributes using:

```
    getSub = ET_Subscriber()
    getSub.auth_stub = myClient
    getSub.props = ["SubscriberKey", "EmailAddress"]
    getSub.search_filter = {'Property' : 'SubscriberKey','SimpleOperator' : 'equals','Value' : SubscriberTestEmail}
    getResponse = getSub.get()
```

but how can I retrieve all data of a subscriber?

Also even if I try to get the property "First_Name", the result informs me that there is no such attribute even though I can see it on the app. I also tried to retrieve  First_Name,FirstName and First Name and none worked. On the other hand "SubscriberKey" and "EmailAddress" work. Where can I see the 'actual name' of each attribute?

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/retrieving_profile_attributes_on_the_subscriber_object.html

Answer (score 0):

Adding ID as one of the properties solved the problem